# My fontawesome icons pop into there position when I click on a tab on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I use fontawesome icons for social media links and also for some visual pieces on my skills page. But when my website loads and I click on a tab and the animations finish, some of the icons pop in. For example, 2 out of my four icons used as visual representation of my skills (ie. 'Sound Design' has a picture of a headphones) pop in once it gets to the 'Skills' part of my site. Could this be a loading issue where it just reads the scripts too slow?

Here is my html (every tab is contained on my index.html document, and I use animations to move 'pages' out of the way to display different pages.)

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c124511129.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!--JQUERY-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src='js/transit.js'></script>

  <title>Ben Lusted | Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="contact-tab">
      <div class="contact-info">
        <h1>get in touch!</h1>
        <p>Email me: blustedaudio@gmail.com</p>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/thebenlusted" title="Twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="https://vimeo.com/thebenlusted" title="Vimeo" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-vimeo-v"></i></a>
        <a href="" title="Dribbble" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
        <a href="" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-work-tab">
      <a href="#my-work-btn" id="my-work-btn" class="nav-link">my work</a>
      <div class="my-work-content">
        <h1>my work</h1>
        <h2 id="work-tagline">Here is what I am good at</h2>
        <div class="skill-card-cont">
          <div class="skill-category-card" id="web-des-skills">
            <i class="far fa-eye" id="eye-hover"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" style="font-size:110px; position:absolute; margin:0; padding:0; transform:translate(-50%,25%);"></i>
            <h3 style="line-height:24px;">Web<br />Design</h3>
            <div class="content-webdes"><br />
              <p>
                I can do this, that, these, those. Oh! And this: \o/
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="skill-category-card" id="web-dev-skills">
            <i class="far fa-eye" id="eye-hover"></i>
            <i class="far fa-file-code" style="font-size:110px; position:absolute; margin:0; padding:0; transform:translate(-50%,25%);"></i>
            <h3 style="line-height:24px;">Web<br />Development</h3>
            <div class="content-webdev"><br />
              <p>
                I can code a dancing monkey for your website
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="skill-category-card" id="gfx-skills">
            <i class="far fa-eye" id="eye-hover"></i>
            <i class="far fa-image" style="font-size:110px; position:absolute; margin:0; padding:0; transform:translate(-50%,25%);"></i>
            <h3 style="line-height:24px;">Graphic<br />Design</h3>
            <div class="content-gfx"><br />
              <p>
                I can make shapes and give them color!
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="skill-category-card" id="sfx-skills">
            <i class="far fa-eye" id="eye-hover"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-volume-up" style="font-size:110px; position:absolute; margin:0; padding:0; transform:translate(-50%,25%);"></i>
            <h3 style="line-height:24px;">Audio<br />Design</h3>
            <div class="content-sfx"><br />
              <p>
                Studied Sound Design for Visual Media at the Vancouver Film School in 2017/18.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-projects">
          <h2 style="font-size:32px;">recent projects</h2>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th><a href="http://www.shotgunfarmers.com/" target="_blank">Shotgun Farmers</a></th>
              <th><a href="https://thebenlusted.github.io/jsauthentication/" target="_blank">JS Authenticator</a></th>
              <th>Audio Imgur</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Shotgun Farmers</th>
              <th>Shotgun Farmers</th>
              <th>Shotgun Farmers</th>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about-tab">
      <a href="#about-btn" id="about-btn" class="nav-link">about</a>
      <div class="about-text">
        <h1>who am I?</h1><br>
        <div class="abt-tagline">
          <h2>My name is Ben Lusted, <br>and I am a web developer.<h2><br>
              <h3>I am a Canadian currently living in Vancouver and looking for
                the next big thing.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
          <img src="images/me.png" alt="ME" class="about-img">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="home-tab">
      <a href="#home-btn" id="home-btn" class="nav-link">home</a>
      <div class="landing-info-text">
        <h1>Ben<br>Lusted,</h1><br>
        <h2>Web Developer.</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="landing-info">
      <a href="#contact-btn" id="contact-btn" class="nav-link">contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also some jQuery stuff to handle page transitions

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.about-text').hide();
  $('.contact-info').hide();
  $('.my-work-content').hide();

  $('#landing-info').animate({
    width: "100%"
  }, 450);
  $('#my-work-tab').animate({
    width: "96%"
  }, 600);
  $('#about-tab').animate({
    width: "92%"
  }, 750);
  $('#home-tab').animate({
    width: "88%"
  }, 900);
});

$(function() {
  $('.skill-category-card').mouseenter(function() {
    if(this.id === 'web-des-skills') {
    $('.content-webdes').animate({top:'70%',opacity:'1'},20);
    $('#web-des-skills').animate({paddingTop:'20px'},20);
  }
    if(this.id === 'web-dev-skills') {
    $('.content-webdev').animate({top:'65%',opacity:'1'},20);
    $('#web-dev-skills').animate({paddingTop:'20px'},20);
  }
    if(this.id === 'gfx-skills') {
    $('.content-gfx').animate({top:'65%',opacity:'1'},20);
    $('#gfx-skills').animate({paddingTop:'20px'},20);
  }
    if(this.id === 'sfx-skills') {
      $('.content-sfx').animate({top:'65%', opacity:'1'},20);
      $('#sfx-skills').animate({paddingTop:'20px'},20);
    }
  });
  $('.skill-category-card').mouseleave(function() {
    if(this.id === 'web-des-skills') {
    $('.content-webdes').animate({top:'-20%',opacity:'0'},25);
    $('#web-des-skills').animate({paddingTop:'0px'},25);
    }
      if(this.id === 'web-dev-skills') {
      $('.content-webdev').animate({top:'-20%',opacity:'0'},25);
      $('#web-dev-skills').animate({paddingTop:'0px'},25);
    }
      if(this.id === 'gfx-skills') {
      $('.content-gfx').animate({top:'-20%',opacity:'0'},25);
      $('#gfx-skills').animate({paddingTop:'0px'},25);
    }
      if(this.id === 'sfx-skills') {
        $('.content-sfx').animate({top:'-20%',opacity:'0'},25);
        $('#sfx-skills').animate({paddingTop: '0px'},25);
      }
  });
});

$(function() {
  let active = "slide-3";
  $('#home-btn').click(function() {
    $('#home-tab').animate({
      width: '88%'
    });
    $('.landing-info-text h1').animate({
      left: '0'
    });
    $('.landing-info-text h2').animate({
      left: '0'
    });

    $('#about-tab').animate({
      width: '92%'
    });
    $('.about-text').animate({
      left: '0px'
    });

    $('#my-work-tab').animate({
      width: '96%'
    });
    $('.my-work-content').animate({
      left: '0px'
    });
  });

  $('#about-btn').click(function() {

    $('#home-tab').animate({
      width: '60'
    });
    $('.landing-info-text h1').animate({
      left: '-1000px'
    });
    $('.landing-info-text h2').animate({
      left: '-1000px'
    });

    $('#about-tab').animate({
      width: '92%'
    });
    $('.about-text').animate({
      left: '0px'
    });
    $('.about-text').show();

    $('#my-work-tab').animate({ width: '96%' });
    $('.my-work-content').animate({
      left: '0px'
    });
  });

  $('#my-work-btn').click(function() {
    $('.my-work-content').show();
    $('#home-tab').animate({
      width: '60'
    });
    $('.landing-info-text h1').animate({
      left: '-1000px'
    });
    $('.landing-info-text h2').animate({
      left: '-1000px'
    });

    $('#about-tab').animate({
      width: '120'
    });
    $('.about-text').animate({
      left: '-1500px'
    });

    $('#my-work-tab').animate({
      width: '96%'
    });
    $('.my-work-content').show();
    $('.my-work-content').animate({
      left: '0px'
    });

  });

  $('#contact-btn').click(function() {
    $('#home-tab').animate({
      width: '60'
    });
    $('.landing-info-text h1').animate({
      left: '-1000px'
    });
    $('.landing-info-text h2').animate({
      left: '-1000px'
    });

    $('#my-work-tab').animate({
      width: '180'
    });
    $('.my-work-content').animate({
      left: '-1500px'
    });

    $('#about-tab').animate({
      width: '120'
    });
    $('.about-text').animate({
      left: '-1500px'
    });

    $('.contact-info').show();
  });
});
```

Finally the css (if necessary):

```
html {
  overflow:hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: #1E1E5D;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* CONTACT */
#landing-info {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #587FFC;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
}

.landing-info-text {
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 300px;
}

.landing-info-text h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 800%;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 100px;
  animation: slide-up-fade-in ease 1.4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  text-shadow: 6px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.landing-info-text h2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  animation: slide-up-fade-in ease 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 24px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  top: 50%;
  right: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link:after {
  border-left: 3px solid white;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  transition: height 250ms ease-in-out 0s;
  height: 0;
}

.nav-link:hover:after {
  transition: height 100ms ease-in-out 0s;
  height: 100%;
}

/* MY WORK */
#my-work-tab {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #92A5FD;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.my-work-content {
  width:85%;
  height:100vh;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin:0;
  transform:translateX(12%);
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  color: white;
}

.my-work-content h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 85px;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 20px;
}
#work-tagline {
  font-size: 38px;
}

.skill-category-card {
  background-color: rgb(68, 79, 83);
  width:220px;
  height:220px;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-right:20px;
  padding:0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  animation: slide-up-fade-in ease 0.8s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  box-shadow:5px 10px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.skill-card-cont {
  position:absolute;
}
.skill-category-card h3 {
  font-size:22px;
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  top:75%;
}
#eye-hover {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  top:6px;
}

.content-webdes, .content-webdev, .content-gfx, .content-sfx {
  background-color:white;
  width:220px;
  height:220px;
  position:relative;
  top:-20%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  color:black;
  font-size:16px;
  opacity:0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.recent-projects {
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  animation: slide-up-fade-in ease-in-out 0.8s;
  z-index: -2;
}
.recent-projects h2 {
  position: relative;
  color:white;
}
.recent-projects table {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  font-size:22px;
  border:4px solid white;
}
.recent-projects a {
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:white;
}


/* ABOUT */
#about-tab {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF8692;
  width: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

#about-tab .about-text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.about-text h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 85px;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 20px;
}

.abt-tagline {
  width: 75%;
}

.abt-tagline h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.abt-tagline h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.cont {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 60%;
}

.cont img {
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: medium;
}

/* HOME */
#home-tab {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF1D58;
  width: 0;
}

#contact-tab {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#contact-tab .contact-info {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px 0 0 210px;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.contact-info h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 85px;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.contact-info p {
  font-size:24px;
}
.contact-info i {
  font-size:42px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:white;
  border-width: thin;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:8px;
  color:white;
  margin-right:20px;
}



footer {
  color:white;
  bottom:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
}
footer h1 {
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:'Poppins';
  opacity: 0.6;
  margin-left:50%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}


/* ELEMENT SLIDE UP AND FADE IN */
@keyframes slide-up-fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 30px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-up-fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 40px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes slide-up-fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 40px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-up-fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 40px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes slide-up-fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 40px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {}
```

Comment: Hi Ben, could you share a screenshot of the issue as the description is not very clear and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to reproduce on codepen and everything seems to be fine except for a visual adjustments not related to the question, check it out here [CodePen Reproduction](https://codepen.io/growload/pen/VwYdRMM)
I'll say you check for any speed, caching and browser issues. Try another browser.
Dont forget the closing html tag thats missing

```
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, haven't done any aspect ratio adjustments. I should crush that out this week.
Still seems really slow for me. Firefox is 10x slower than checking on Chrome.
I'll keep working and see what happens. Maybe my PC is just chugging along right now, who knows. Thanks for checking for me regardless!

Comment: You can also try to download all the dependencies like (fontawesome, jquery, googlefonts ) to your system and load them locally and see if that increase the speed if thats the issue. you can switch back to cdn when you're live